# Does anyone know of an automation tool that will perform actions on sending or receiving of an email?

Tags: automated-testing, email

I need to test that a series of sites are up and running and that they can send and receive email.

Step one: send email from example1@example.com

Step two: expect response email emailServerOne@example.com within a given amount of time.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3825/outlook-mail-testing/3827#3827

Comment: @SamWoods What would you think the feasibility of automating this under a CI server like Jenkins would be?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  Do the e-mails need to be sent from a certain domain, or could you use a free e-mail such as gmail like in the answer I linked to?  Can you give a bit more context about the scenario you want to automate?  What is the goal of the automation?

Comment: @SamWoods Yes I am considering using an account like gmail to send the automated emails.  I don't need to to be from a specific domain.  I am trying to send automated emails (several times a day) to 15+ instances of a web application, then after a to be determined period of time expect a response email.  Basically testing that the applications can send and receive emails multiple times a day.  On a failure I would need a notification (email, text, ...)

Comment: If you are just testing the capabilities of the software and not any public domains, I would suggest you run locally some small mailer and smtp server, and use those from the test script for sending and receiving the emails.

Comment: Yep, you should definitely be able to do this under a CI server, you can either use SMTP (may be able to use the one your IT department already uses, if that is what they use) or you can go the route of using a gmail account, instructions in my first comment's link.

Comment: @samwoods Going to start with a gmail account for ease of use.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

If those are the only requirements then a simple (well, not so simple but not very complex) script in Perl, Python or your favorite scripting language will achieve the same results for free with greater flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at  Febooti. It is an open-source program that can create/send emails. I was using it prior to send an email with test results every morning once my test suites were finished.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Parasoft SOAtest would be able to handle this. It would enable you to send emails and apply a time based assertion on receiving the response. On a failure it could then email you with an alert.
http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/soatest.jsp